# How can i realloc the dynamic array after returning null by malloc in c?

Tags: malloc, realloc

I wanna write a program which should receive a input in form of string,
and this input will save in a dynamic array, so I use malloc with a for example 20*sizeof, and I want if the size of string was longer than my allocating memory, improve it's size. But I receive a crash and cannot improve it's size with realloc.

What can I do?

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  char *user;
  int n = 0;
  user = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
  scanf("%s",user);
  n = strlen(user);
  user = (char*)realloc(user,n);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `m` modifier in scanf:

```
char *user = 0;
scanf("%ms", &user);
// use 'user' -- will be null if there was an error reading.
```

Unfortunately, this is only available on POSIX systems.  On other systems, you'll need to write your own loop reading characters with `getchar`, and reallocate as you read (as needed).